# Conan.io - is it possible to do something similar to "python setup.py develop"?

Tags: c++, deployment, dependencies, package-managers, conan

I'm developing a C++ package "dep" which I want to use in project "app 1" and "app 2" while developing both "dep", "app 1" and "app 2". The current workflow consists of calling

- `conan export` in "dep", and
- `conan install --build` in "app 1" and "app 2"

for every small change made in "dep". This process is tedious and causes a complete rebuild of "dep" every time.

I'm aware of the "test_package" function in Conan, but it requires the projects "app 1" and "app 2" to reside in the same tree as "dep", which is not an option.

In Python's setuptools it is possible to use "python setup.py develop" to install a package in a way that makes any changes immediately available to any package depending on it. Is it possible to do something similar in Conan where "dep" would be updated (if there are any changes) before building "app 1" and "app 2"?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean with "test_package" requires the projects app1 and app2 to be in the same tree as "dep".

Comment: If I understand the [documentation](http://conanio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/packaging/testing.html) correctly, the "test_package" command can be used to quickly build "dep" and test a package (such as "app 1"). This is close to what I want to achieve, which is to easily build any changes in "dep", then build "app 1", and then run "app 1" to see if everything works. But "app 1" can't be placed inside a "test_package" folder in "dep" in my case, as in the documentation example.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood "test_package". It is able to create a package, and test a package with any desired number of apps or tests of the package. It is not intended to build one useful app, but just a test that everything is building and linking properly. If app1, and app2 are your "products" or useful applications, of course they should be independent. So the answer about "--build=missing" could be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to issue the `--build` all the time. That option is forcing to re-build the full dependency tree. You can use:

```
$ conan install --build=missing
or
$ conan install --build=app1
```

Irrespective of using `test_package` or not, the dependency will not be rebuilt.

Comment: Yes, that works, but manually. I am wondering if there is any automatic way to detect changes in the source of "dep", and if there are changes, do `conan export` in "dep" and `conan install --build dep` in "app 1". I would like to be able to see the changes in the sources of "dep" immediately. Similar to the behavior I would get if I included the sources of "dep" in the "app 1" project and built everything in one go. But I completely understand if this currently is not an option in Conan.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are talking about CI, and conan is a package manager. Maybe the flow should be the opposite: The CI detects there is a change in "dep", then fires the re-build of "dep" with test_package. Then, the command "conan info --build-order" might help the CI system to know if it has to rebuild dependents on "dep"

Comment: Yes, the automation I'm looking for might have to be part of something like a CI system. I guess I just wanted the convenience of "python setup.py develop" in Conan, but it is definitely a feature that is way easier to implement for Python packages because they don't have to be built when the source changes, which of course is the case in C++. Thanks for the feedback!